# Automated Google Analytics Reporting Monthly Emails Only Showing A Single Day

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have configured a dashboard for Google Analytics, selected (using the date drop down menu at the top right) to show one months worth of data and have compared it to the previous month. I then configured monthly emails to be sent to me and to test I did the same thing again, but instead configured the emails to email me daily.

The email came in this morning and only shows a single days worth of Analytics information...

Despite using the calendars to show a months worth of data, since I selected a frequency as 'daily' will Google only show me one days worth of Analytics? Can I expect my monthly email to show a months worth of data?

**NOTE:**

The question may sound obvious, but to time frame I can't wait until the end of the month to receive the monthly email to see if this will work, because if it emails me and only shows me one days worth of information I'll have to wait another month to see if attempts to fix it have worked.

**NOTE #2:**

I'm not sure if maybe I am being stupid but from my research what I have described above should work, but Google's documentation is a little vague, I have been going off what I have read on various blogs with regards to my specific requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you set the *Frequency* to *daily* you will only receive a days worth of information, despite what the time frame in the report is.  In other words it will only send you the new data generated from report to report.

If you are wanting to test it, choose *Monthly* for the *Frequency*, then select tomorrows date as the *Day of Month* that you want to receive it.  That way you will get a report tomorrow, but with an entire months worth of data.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't come through, it looks like it must 'collect' a months worth of data on the email before it comes through. This supports your first paragraph also.

Comment: That's to bad.  It would be nice to know for sure it will work without having to wait a month.  I hate testing time sensitive stuff like that.

Comment: I will mark this question as answered at the end of the month when I know if the reporting has worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your custom dashboard that you are building for the report that you specify "last 7 days" or "last 30 days" in the pulldown in the upper right so that when it sends out sends out emails you get data for the whole week or month and can see trends as opposed to a single data point.